# HM-10 BLE controller is not responding to some AT commands

Tags: arduino-nano, android, ble

I have HM-10 BLE controller and it is not responding to some AT commands which I need to use.

AT commands which don't work:

- `AT+TYPE2` returns `+TYPE=0`
- `AT+VERR?` not responding
- `AT+VERS?` not responding
- `AT+RESTART` not responding
- `AT` not responding but `AT+`responds with `OK`
- `AT+VERSION` responding with `MLT-BT05-V4.1`

The most important command for me is `AT+TYPE2` because even if I set pin with command `AT+PIN112233`, in my Android App, `AlertDialog` with `password` field is not activated during connection with `bleGatt = bleDevice.connectGatt(this, true, bleGattCallback)` function.

I even tried to call `createBond()` function on this device, but it is not returning anything. I need to activate pairing with password with `AT+TYPE2` but its always returning 0 which is default connection without password and pairing method.

I'm not sure if I have some bugged HM-10 controller but I cant even reset it to default settings.
It is working fine with transfering data by characteristics but other stuff is not working.

I've used some weird iterating function to print out AT+HELP commands for this controller and AT+TYPE is not listed there as a command. That means I cant set pairing method? What kind of BLE device has pairing disabled and there is not option to set up at least password?

Here are my commands

```
21:01:19.739 ->  Command             Description                       
21:01:19.880 ->  ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
21:01:19.949 ->  AT                  Check if the command terminal work normally  
21:01:20.054 ->  AT+RESET            Software reboot                   
21:01:20.159 ->  AT+VERSION          Get firmware, bluetooth, HCI and LMP version 
21:01:20.271 ->  AT+HELP             List all the commands                 
21:01:20.365 ->  AT+NAME             Get/Set local device name                    
21:01:20.459 ->  AT+PIN              Get/Set pin code for pairing                 
21:01:20.552 ->  AT+PASS             Get/Set pin code for pairing                 
21:01:20.646 ->  AT+BAUD             Get/Set baud rate                         
21:01:20.740 ->  AT+LADDR            Get local bluetooth address           
21:01:20.880 ->  AT+ADDR             Get local bluetooth address           
21:01:20.950 ->  AT+DEFAULT          Restore factory default               
21:01:21.054 ->  AT+RENEW            Restore factory default               
21:01:21.157 ->  AT+STATE            Get current state                 
21:01:21.271 ->  AT+PWRM             Get/Set power on mode(low power)          
21:01:21.365 ->  AT+POWE             Get/Set RF transmit power         
21:01:21.459 ->  AT+SLEEP            Sleep mode                            
21:01:21.553 ->  AT+ROLE             Get/Set current role.                     
21:01:21.693 ->  AT+PARI             Get/Set UART parity bit.                     
21:01:21.787 ->  AT+STOP             Get/Set UART stop bit.                       
21:01:21.834 ->  AT+START            System start working.             
21:01:21.952 ->  AT+IMME             System wait for command when power on.    
21:01:22.056 ->  AT+IBEA             Switch iBeacon mode.                      
21:01:22.161 ->  AT+IBE0             Set iBeacon UUID 0.                           
21:01:22.264 ->  AT+IBE1             Set iBeacon UUID 1.                           
21:01:22.381 ->  AT+IBE2             Set iBeacon UUID 2.                           
21:01:22.475 ->  AT+IBE3             Set iBeacon UUID 3.                           
21:01:22.569 ->  AT+MARJ             Set iBeacon MARJ .                        
21:01:22.663 ->  AT+MINO             Set iBeacon MINO .                        
21:01:22.756 ->  AT+MEA              Set iBeacon MEA .                         
21:01:22.850 ->  AT+NOTI             Notify connection event .                    
21:01:22.967 ->  AT+UUID             Get/Set system SERVER_UUID .                  
21:01:23.071 ->  AT+CHAR             Get/Set system CHAR_UUID .                
21:01:23.174 ->  -----------------------------------------------------------------
21:01:23.257 ->  Note: (M) = The command support slave mode only.
```

Comment: use AT+HELP to list the available commands

Comment: where did you buy the module?

Comment: https://www.banggood.com/KEYES-HM-10-6-Pin-Transparent-BLE-Bluetooth-V4_0-Serial-Port-Module-With-Logic-Level-Translator-p-1023524.html?cur_warehouse=CN

Comment: Its weird that it has functional PASS and PIN commands but no way to activate pairing :D

Comment: it has some minimal firmware

Comment: Probably but I dont know how to update it because I dont know what is firmware version and what kind of firmware will work with this.

Answer (score 1):

same as me... clone of a hm10.
not very much info on this board.
at command doesn't works when they are in caps ..
no need ? or = after command.
you can paired with at+connX (x is the device number, the first founded is 1. the second is 2, etc etc).
it cannot auto connect even if you paired them before.
not much range (7 meter).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).